# Proper syntax of strpos in php query

Tags: php, strpos

In php i have a line of code that queries the database to finds the # of messages that have been posted within a chat room since the user last logged in. I would also like for the string to look for a substring inside the data.messages as well ( the users "nickname"). can someone please show me how to syntax this correctly

working

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(d.msgid) as con,d.msgid FROM `data` as d where d.room= '".$row['room']."' and d.msgid>(select u.lastmsgnotified from user as u where u.id='".$row['id']."') order by d.msgid desc limit 0,1"));
```

New Code

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(d.msgid) as con2,d.msgid FROM `data` as d where d.room= '".$row['room']."' and d.msgid>(select u.lastmsgnotified from user as u where u.id='".$row['id']."') and strpos(d.message,$row[nickname])!==false order by d.msgid desc limit 0,1"));


if(intval($row2['con2'])>1){
        sendGCM($row2['con2']." New Alerts in ".$row['room'],$row['deviceid']);
    }else if(intval($row2['con2'])>0){
    $rok = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select u.*,m.* from user as u, `data` as m where u.id=m.userid and m.msgid=".$row2['msgid']));
        if($rok['nickname']=='')
        $rok['nickname'] = 'A User';
        sendGCM($rok['nickname']." Has Alerted you in room '".$rok['room']."'",$row['deviceid']);
    }
```

Comment: that's nasty code. NEVER chain database calls like that. You're simply assuming nothing could ever failed, and chaining like that will simply compound the failure into bigger problems.

Comment: Do you have an example of a better way to do this query? Also do you know the answer to my syntax question for strpos()

Comment: `$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);`. as for strpos, http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, that in your $row2= line you are using a PHP function strpos()
If you want to do that in a MySQL query you will need to use the MySQL function LOCATE() (and you will likely need to use a sub select @ that point).

Here's the MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Hope that helps.

NOTE: You could also check out this list of other MySQL string functions to see if you'd prefer to use one of them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html